# NetBeans not generating @author and @version of javaDoc?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, javadoc

NetBeans by default will not generate documentation from @author and @version tags. How do I enable this from within the IDE?

Edit: There is indeed an option within NetBeans to display these tags. Run>Set Project Configuration>Customize... Expand Build and select Documenting - the checkboxes are right in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify build.xml, the build file for Ant. Redefine your "javadoc" target to include all of the information you see fit. The solution is independent from NetBeans, so it'll work with any Ant-based build environment.

[Here](http://firstclassthoughts.co.uk/ant/javadoc.html) are some very concrete instructions.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I found the NetBeans specific ant properties file, it is: (project)/nbproject/project.properties - set the values for author and version to true just as your link explained for Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible in the settings:

**`right click on project -> properties -> (Build) -> Documenting`**, check both tags below **`Document Additional Tags`**.